# Rails 2 routes to rails 3 conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

does anyone know if there is a rails routes converter online? I was not able to find one. I am trying to convert this line:

```
map.add_payment_profile 'add_payment_profile/:id', :controller => 'payment_profile_controller', :action => 'add_payment_profile'
```

---

Thanks!! So if I understand correctly:

```
map.create_cim_payment_profile 'create_cim_payment_profile_user', :controller => 'authorize_net', :action => 'create_cim_payment_profile', :only => :post would be

match 'create_cim_payment_profile_user' => 'payment_profile#create_cim_payment_profile', :as => :create_cim_payment_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
match 'add_payment_profile/:id' => 'payment_profile#add_payment_profile',
          :as => :add_payment_profile
```

Rails 3 has a new `controller#action` shorthand for mapping controller actions. You will also need to specify `:as` to created a named route.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will work:

```
match 'add_payment_profile/:id',:controller => "payment_profile_controller", 
         :action => "add_payment_profile"
```